# How do I copy database file from dataDirectory to www folder in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to download a database file from the server and use it in the apk.

I downloaded the file at 'cordova.file.dataDirectory'. The file was downloaded successfully at the desired location but on the window.plugins.sqlDB.copy() function, the application crashed and display the message.

> Unfortunately application has stopped.

Named file created at databases directory with only 'android_metadata' table

The code I used:

```
var url = encodeURI("my server path");
var store = cordova.file.dataDirectory; 
var fileName = "Sample";
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store + fileName, appStart, downloadAsset);
function downloadAsset() {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(url, store+fileName,function (entry) {
            if       (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
                window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("Sample", 0, copysuccess, copyerror);
            }
            function copysuccess() {
                //open db and run your queries
               //app.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "Sample"   });
            }

            function copyerror(e) {
                //db already exists or problem in copying the db file. Check   the Log.
                //app.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "Sample"   });
            }

            },

        function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
}
 function appStart() {
    alert('file available');
}
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to the `www` directory in a Cordova application - it is read-only.

The documentation for the [copy method](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy#copy) of [cordova-plugin-dbcopy](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy) states:

> This Method allows you the copy the database from www directory.

i.e. it allows you copy an existing DB **from** the www directory **to** another directory, e.g. the platform-specific app persistent storage location indicated by `cordova.file.dataDirectory`

Comment: I solved this issue by using fileTransfer.download() method. On success function I changed code with                                                              app.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "Sample"   }); instead  of  ' window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("Sample", 0, copysuccess, copyerror);'

Comment: Thank you @DaveAlden for reply